# Joomla: Warning: strpos() [function.strpos]: Empty delimiter in libraries\joomla\environment\uri.php on line 162

Tags: php, iis, joomla1.5

After installing Joomla 1.5.x on an IIS 7, instead of seeing the expected sample data I see an un-styled (sample data) page and this message at the very top of the page:

Joomla: Warning: strpos() [function.strpos]: Empty delimiter in [installdir]\libraries\joomla\environment\uri.php on line 162

How can I fix that?

Comment: This should be on serverfault.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is a work-around or the real answer, but setting the variable $live_site = 'base URL' (ex: http://www.site.com) in [install dir]/configuration.php seems to work.